# C++ IDE for Solaris SPARC

Tags: c++, ide, sparc, solaris-10

We've been given a C++ code base that was apparently developed using Rational Apex as the front end. In our opinion, Apex is less than ideal for C++ development.

We're looking for an IDE we can use that has syntax highlighting, code-walking (go to definition, show usages), and isn't a pain to use.

We've looked at NetBeans, Sun Studio and Understand. NetBeans is fighting us every step of the way, Sun Studio is lacking in features, and Understand is not really an IDE, but we're looking at trying to force it to be one with macros.

There are other questions on SO that are similar, but they seem to be more directed questions (and more obscure).

What I'd like to know is what Solaris developers use. Do we need to give NetBeans or Sun Studio another look, or is there something we missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Last time I was working on a Solaris codebase, I used Visual Studio. Yes, the Microsoft product. Modern versions of Both Visual Studio and Sun Studio are fairly standards compliant. As a result, I could debug application logic on Windows. For the low-level stuff we relied on Qt. As a bonus, once you've got the port to x86-64/Win done, supporting x86-64/Solaris becomes trivial.

Comment: +1 for this.  I've developed for TONNES of different platforms and I've ALWAYS done it on a windows machine with Visual Studio.  No other IDE out there comes even close, IMO.  You don't have to use the standard compiler you can get VStudio to run a make file or any other build processing software you can think of.

Comment: Yes, it's eminently possible to run a cross-compiler under Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse CDT using gcc.

Comment: I thought Eclipse wasn't supported on Solaris any more.

Comment: At least 3.4.1 is still available. http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.4.1-200809111700/solPlatform.php

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the Code::Blocks IDE (which I can strongly recommend) will work on Solaris - see [this link](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_from_source_on_Solaris). Having said that, all my own (quite considerable) Solaris C++ programming has been done with vi and make, which is certainly a viable option.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing... Code::Blocks.  vi and make works for you, emacs and make work for me.

Comment: Use vim rather than vi! Just like vi but better.
Syntax highlighting and a bunch of useful bundled marcros. "Open as Diff" feature is great for working out what you dun on Friday after you came back from lunch at the Pub.

Comment: I didn't have a good experience with codeblocks and finally went with eclipse cdt. It's not as good as I'd like either but it's workable. I couldn't get help with either cdt on their forums.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have three options in solaris(or linux);

1. Eclipse with cdt.
2. Emacs with [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/),[ecb](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) and [xrefactory](http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html). (*)
3. [Slickedit](http://www.slickedit.com/)

(*)cedet(semantic) is good for code completion but not good enough for template based codes.

Answer (score 1):

The SunStudio IDE actually used to be half-decent when it was called Forte. Nowadays it seems to be some java NetBeans derivative horror. Last time i worked on Solaris i ended up mounting my home dir onto windows over Samba and using either Eclipse or Visual Studio to edit code. You can create a dummy (in the sense that it doesn't get used for compiling) project and auto-complete and like should work. That does mean command-line compiling and debugging back on Solaris though.

I think C++ on Solaris ceased to be a viable development platform once Sun shifted their attention to Java...

Comment: I find the C/C++ compiler and development pretty good. It's complicated to get a complete Sun CC compatible build chain but the result is fine. LockLint and DTrace are also interesting tools. But the IDE well they have NetBeans and volunteers as Sun have given up the Desktop market - even for developers - completely. It's a shame but thats what it is and i'm sure it will get worse with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest sparc solaris eclipse from [this page](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/index.php). Then add CDT in the normal way, using the [Galileo update site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#updatemanager).

[CDT 6.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn60) is the first version of the Eclipse C/C++ support that really counts as competitive with VS. And you can use it in the same way on either a PC or the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if you wouldn't consider it an IDE, but [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) + [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) never failed me. If CEDET isn't perfect, you still have your head. :) 
 That's of course if Emacs would work on that SPARC of yours, I wouldn't know, but I believe it will work just fine. Worth every hour you spend learning to use it. Here's a [tutorial](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) on how to get started.

Answer (score -1):

**Slickedit** (400-500US$) is definite the best option for you.

Source Navigator (a dead open source project) will also compile on Sparc machines but i don't think the editor is great.

Why are you bound to SPARC? It's dated and without future.

If you aren't using a special SPARC feature or SPARC assembly i would develop against posix und unix 2005 specification and use Linux where you have more options.